# Hide a table row when a checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript

I am testing this [table](http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/434-2/) and i am trying to hide some rows when a `checkbox` is checked.

For example in my case: when the checkbox 3.5 is cheked the table **rows** that contain Zimmer 2.5 and 4.5 are **hidden**.

Or for example if the checkbox 2.5 is cheked the table rows with Zimmer 3.5 or 4.5 are not visible.

I tried to give a checkbox a data-number but nothing...

I tried `<input type="checkbox" data-number="3.5" />`

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I tried something like this JS:

```
jQuery(document.body).on('change', "#row2", function() { 
jQuery("#tablepress-id-5 tr.row2").toggle(!this.checked); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do it the other way around - the checkbox should have a value based on the number it represents and the table row can have a data attribute indicating the number of rooms.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms_check" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms_check" value="3">
<input type="checkbox" name="rooms_check" value="4">
<table>
    <tr data-number="2">
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-number="3">
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
        <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then with JS:

```
$('input[name="rooms_check"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="rooms_check"]').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('tr[data="'+$(this).val()+'"]').hide();
        } else {
            $('tr[data="'+$(this).val()+'"]').show();
        }
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's how you could do it without changing the table html.

```
$('input[name="rooms_check"]').change(function(){
    $('input[name="rooms_check"]').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).prop('checked')) {
            $('tr').has('td:nth-child(2):contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').hide();
        } else {
            $('tr').has('td:nth-child(2):contains("'+$(this).val()+'")').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip but unfortunally i can't edit the HTML file and i can't give the row that `data-number` value. Is there a method in JS to read and display only the rows that contains the desidered value like 3.5 for example?

Comment: You can, but it's very inconvenient. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.
And in this case i have to add my value like this `.val(2.5)`?

Comment: I tried the last JS you wrote but nothing. http://ap.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/434-2/

Comment: The value should be set for each checkbox, see the html above.

Comment: You have to set the checkboxes name and value. And please provide code samples instead of images, I can't understand what you do only by seeing an image.

Comment: i tried `<input name="rooms_check" value="2.5" type="checkbox">2.5<br>
<input name="rooms_check" value="3.5" type="checkbox">3.5<br>
<input name="rooms_check" value="4.5" type="checkbox">4.5`

This is the code.

Comment: Here https://jsfiddle.net/dn3q9vc3/. I adjusted the code, the above was removing only the cells. I will update the answer now as well.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help. I am lloking forward to try it

Answer (score 0):

I believe some javascript should fire when you click the checkbox and make the expected rows disappear. Do you have the relevant javascript there?

Comment: Sorry don't know JQuery. Just a thought instead of document.body could it be the actual checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Hi A Casa try this code

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('change',function(e){
v=$(this).val();
$('td:contains("+v+")').parent('tr').toggle()
})
```